# Google Font don't work on my joomla page

Tags: html, css, joomla, fonts

I have a joomla website template that uses google font 'Open Sans'. The font source file is linked inside the head tag as

`<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,400,300,600,700&subset=latin,greek" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

I have greek characters and inside my style.css , I have

`@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&subset=latin,greek);`

I tried both but it doesn't work in any borwser except in my chrome. (only on my pc not in other pc's) So I'm really wondering what's happening. 
Plz help :)
Website URL: [link](http://www.pinkunderwear.gr)

Comment: please give us some relevant code that reproduce the issue minimally

Comment: I see it loading in Chrome's developers tools. I know this seems silly but are you not seeing it load locally, or actually when it's published online?  If it's just locally, it's because you're using "//" at the beginning, which will try to prepend file: to that on a local machine, and http: on the web.

Comment: @plushyObject I don't see it online

Answer (score 0):

This goes in your template index.php file:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&subset=latin,greek' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

And this goes in your template css file:

```
body {font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;}
```

Also make sure you don't have any other fonts overriding your css such as h1, h2, h3, p, etc...

Comment: it is already like that but not working. No overrides, every font is Open Sans.